# Clicked voting arrows on sites with responsive design show with wrong color under Internet Explorer 11

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, voting, internet-explorer

On sites with the new responsive design, the color of clicked vote buttons have a theme color related to the site's design.

However, on Internet Explorer 11, this arrow always shows as orange, regardless of the site. This seems to have been copied from Stack Overflow. Can this please be fixed?

Here's a screenshot of the vote buttons on a post I've upvoted, loaded on Internet Explorer 11. The site is Meta Stack Exchange, whose theme color is light blue, but this happens on all sites with the responsive design:

> [image: Clicked arrow looks orange]

Now here's the same screenshot using Microsoft Edge, which properly displays the theme color blue for MSE:

> [image: Clicked arrow looks blue]

Comment: Can reproduce in IE11. Seems to not recognize the filter value that changes it. (said style isn't supported in IE11 anyway)

Comment: This weird off-color is also noticed on non IE browsers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371999/578411

Comment: @rene That's for comment upvotes, and is only briefly visible, while this is for posts and is *always* visible, even if the vote was cast from a browser that displays it properly.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the difference, otherwise I would have said: cross-site duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed recently.

I've tried looking at my prior votes on different sites (which now all have the responsive design), and on all of them they now appear with the correct theme color instead of Stack Overflow orange.