# Cannot upload images from web links in Internet Explorer 11; buttons cut off

Tags: bug, design, uploader, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer 11, with the new image upload UI, it's not possible for users to upload images from web links. There is a known focus bug where one has to click in the white space outside the gray box before pasting, but while the workaround did work for me in Edge, it *didn't* work for me in IE11.

Additionally, the buttons are cut off and there's a spurious type cursor that doesn't appear in Edge:

[image: Malformed image upload UI in IE11]

Comment: I honestly didn't know IE was still in use, outside corp envs.

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 is five years and thirteen days old. Nobody should use or support it.

Comment: I think [four](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317613/switch-to-the-old-image-uploader-if-disable-responsiveness-button-is-enabled) questions, including this one,  about bugs with [Internet Explorer's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317242/meta-logo-appears-too-high-in-internet-explorer-11?s=2|75.3405) 10 and/or 11 are [three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312895/clicked-voting-arrows-on-sites-with-responsive-design-show-with-wrong-color-unde) too many. :¬l I'm sure you could incorporate this glitch in one of the other three questions.

Comment: Here's a surprise, today in the US there are more IE browser users than there are of Firefox https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/test-centre/software/best-web-browsers-3635255/

Comment: IE11 is the latest release of Internet Explorer, updated last a couple of months ago. Many corporate environments still only support IE, as they're also stuck on Windows 7  (and that's even older) so they don't have edge and don't allow browser installations. This seems like a valid, easily reproducible bug report, downvoting it because you don't like the browser even though it is supported both by its vendor and by Stack Exchange is plain stupid.

Comment: IE11 is shipped inside Windows 10, so mainstream support is still there for a long time, but I agree the usage % is low compared to Chrome.